# Need to validate the Input Date is in correct format(mmddyyyy)

Tags: bash, date

I am trying to validate the date entered by the user(mmddyyyy),used the below but its not working, please correct me where i am wrong.

```
 date  "+%m%d%Y" -d "02012019" > /dev/null  2>&1
        echo $?
```

Comment: How does the user enter the date? by a simple `read` command?

Comment: via command line he will pass  ,ex: sh xx.sh -f 02122029

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use `date` in that way (at least, not the GNU implementation) - it parses the string given via `-d` using its own built-in rules, then if successful outputs the resulting date in the specified format. AFAIK it does not attempt to use the output format to parse strings given as an inputs via `-d` (as, for example, `strptime` would).

Comment: @Renga in your comment you use `sh`. The script must be interpreted by `/bin/sh`, or could be `/bin/bash`?

Comment: Also the point that the user can enter the input date in several alternative valid formats, like `@1613412105` or `'now + 23 days'` or `'last tuesday'`, which all return a zero status.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity,i am using bash.

Comment: And do you want to reject things like 02292021 as there's no 29th of February in 2021?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant i am using a case to validate those,like special  charcters alpha and blank.i am stuck in to validate the date, for example if the user pass the input as 21022023 or 1202 , i have to validate that.

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas yes,the above code is working fine for yyyymmdd or yyyyddmm.. only isue is with mmddyyyy.i am plan to parse the date and rearrange  it by yyyymmdd or yyyyddmm   ang going to compare..

Comment: "_`sh xx.sh -f 02122029`_" you're not using `bash` because you've explicitly specified `sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is a possible approach:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

d="$1"

[[ ! "$d" =~ ^[0-9]{8}$ ]] && \
  echo "Illegal number of characters, or not numbers." && \
  exit

d="${d:4}${d:2:2}${d:0:2}"

date  "+%m%d%Y" -d"$d" > /dev/null 2>&1

[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "Invalid date." || echo "Valid date."
```

---

```bsh
$ ./xx.sh 0201201x
Illegal number of characters, or not numbers.
$ ./xx.sh 0201201900000
Illegal number of characters, or not numbers.
$ ./xx.sh 32022019
Invalid date
$ ./xx.sh 02022019
Valid date.
```

---

Now `01022019` would be a valid date, but if the user typed the day first and then the month, you would need another set of validations for your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks alot,i just edited the parsing section(d="${d:4}${d:0:2}${d:2:2}") and working fine .

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
date=${1?No date specified}

zmodload zsh/datetime || exit
if
  strftime -rs t %m%d%Y "$date" 2> /dev/null &&
  strftime -s canonical_date_for_t %m%d%Y "$t" 2> /dev/null &&
  [[ $date = $canonical_date_for_t ]]
then
  print -r -- $date is valid
else
  print -ru2 -- ${(q+)date} is invalid
  exit 1
fi
```

`strftime -r` calls `strptime()` which parses the input `$date` according to `%m%d%Y`. While `strftime` without `-r` converts back to a `%m%d%Y` formatted date using `strftime()`.

`strptime()` would accept a `02292019` (and treat it like `03012019`), but once converted back with `strftime()`, that becomes `03012019` so would be rejected. Similarly `12310001` (0001-12-31) would be rejected as `12311` would be expected instead (`%Y` for year 1 AC is `1`, not `0001`; replace `%Y` with `%4Y` in the second `strftime` invocation, if you'd rather `0001` be the *expected* representation of year `1`).